# How to change height of UICollectionView outlet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have and UICollectionView and I want change programmatically the height of collectionView.

I'm using:

```
[self.myCollectionInStoryboard.collectionViewLayout collectionViewContentSize];

- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
 {   
   return CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 800);
}
```

But it isn't work... I have added this to my viewController:

```
<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

How can I change this height property to my collectionView?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code does not do what you think it does. You can change the `UICollectionView`'s `frame` property like so: `self.myCollectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 800)`

Comment: That was probably the easiest option I've found around. Just FYI, in Swift 4 you'd have to change CGRectMake to CGRect :)